# Sandbox refresh with my domain

Tags: single-sign-on, mydomain

I read and checked that the "My Domains" of production orgs and sandboxes are managed separetely, which means that a specific domain can be available on a sandbox for a specific POD (ie. cs81) and not available in production or in another POD and vice-versa.

So I try to figure out how Salesforce ensures that when I will refresh or create a sandbox from my production which has a "My Domain" that this domain is not already registered by another customer on an sandbox with the same name on the same POD ?

Production:

```
<mydomain>.my.saleforce.com
```

Sandbox:

```
<mydomain--sandboxName>.<csXX>.my.salesforce.com
```

Do they search an available POD without my production domain already registerd (with my sandbox name) in the sandbox creation process ?

I also noticed that the domain registered for a sandbox is used in the Lightning URL without mentioning POD:

```
<mydomain>--<sandbox name>.lightning.force.com
```

Is there a risk of conflicts if 2 sandboxes use the same "mydomain" and "sandbox name" on 2 different PODs ?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you shouldn't be trying to create sandboxes with the same name because usernames in your org are appended with the name of the sandbox. For that reason, I don't believe the Sandbox UI will even allow you to do that.

If you're concerned about someone from another org creating a sandbox with the same name and MyDomain on the same Pod as one that yours is located on, the `MyDomain` name will show as unavailable to them if they try to create that `MyDomain`. Ditto to you if you were to try to create the `MyDomain` name for your sandbox if someone else were using it. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thank you @crmprogdev for your contribution. My question was more a theorical question, I just curious to know how Salesforce will manage the following scenario:
1/ CompanyA creates a sandbox named "test" with the my Domain "dom1" on POD CS12

`dom1--test.cs12.my.salesforce.com`

2/ CompanyB set the Domain "dom1" in its production env 

`dom1.my.salesforce.com`

and then CompanyB tries to create a sandbox named "test". So Salesforce should have a mechanism to not create the sandbox on cs12 because 

`dom1--test.cs12.my.salesforce.com` 

is already registered. Is it more clear?

Comment: Because it's already registered with ICANN, the 2nd MyDomain of the same name simply cannot be created.